# How to create an index for foreign key in Grails GORM

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm

Suppose you have the following domain classes

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
}

class Book {
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}
```

Gorm adds a user_id column and a foreign key to the Book table. How can I add an index on this column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the simplest way works as expected. You don't need to specify the foreign key or something else.

```
class Book {
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
    static mapping = {
        user index:'index_book_user_id'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Grails allows you to do this by default.  You can specify that Grails use an existing index in the table for particular columns, but I think to create indexes on columns that aren't indexed by default in Grails you'll need to manually create the indexes yourself.

[Reference on GORM index use](http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#ormdsl)